# Restring : App is crashing while opening dialog or Long press on text in webview in Android Q

Tags: android, webview, android-10.0

I am using **Restring library** for give multi language support to my app. Multi language is working fine but my app is crashing when i click on `webview` select box (for open dialog)

Here is my crash log

```
  2020-09-01 17:54:27.910 23346-23346/com.xxx.xx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.xxx.xx, PID: 23346
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:276)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2382)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1276)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:48)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:428)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:419)
    at KA.getView(PG:2)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3271)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1464)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1370)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at 
     com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:146)
    at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:71)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1016)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2325)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2204)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9069)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Library for multilanguage

```
 // Replace bundled strings dynamically
 implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.restring:restring:4.0.5'

// Intercept view inflation
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

// Allows to update the text of views at runtime without recreating the activity
implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.reword:reword:1.1.0'
```

Base activity code

```
 @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

    super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(Restring.wrapContext(newBase)));
 }

 @Override
 public Resources getResources() {
    return Restring.wrapContext(getBaseContext()).getResources();
 }
```

If i comment above attachBaseContext code then error is not coming but multi language is not working

Comment: Problem is it is trying to get a resource string which is not present in your code. you need to identify that which resource is that.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed issue is coming in webview , when i am long press on webview text

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I got the same